# how to add the icon for swipeable tabs

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am downloading the code from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) i want to dispaly tabs with icon how can posssible please help me.

[image]

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Text", "Photo", "Record" ,"Tag"};


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    };

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));


        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 27):

If you are using a `TabLayout`, just do this (This example uses three tabs):

```
 //An array containing your icons from the drawable directory
 final int[] ICONS = new int[]{
            R.drawable.icon_1,
            R.drawable.icon_2,
            R.drawable.icon_3
    };

    //Get reference to your Tablayout
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(ICONS[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(ICONS[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(ICONS[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks! This one worked for me. Solutions on other related SO questions are flagging "deprecated".

Answer (score 25):

Add .setIcon(resources.getDrawable(DrawableIDHere)) in your for loop, and also alter your for loop a bit.

```
// Adding Tabs
for (int i=0; i < tabs.length; i++)
{
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i])
                         .setIcon(resources.getDrawable(ICONS[i]))
                         .setTabListener(this));
}//endfor
```

Also, don't forget to put the right drawable ID's in your ICONS array!

Comment: .setIcon(resources.GetDrwable(ICONS[i]))

resources cannot be resolved error.. what is this??

Comment: you need to use `getResources()` instead

Answer (score 4):

```
// here you add an array of your icon   
 final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            };

    // add this following code to solve your problem
    // here NewsFeedActivity.this.getResources() is used to get the drawable folder resource
    // instead of NewsFeedActivity you have to use your activity name here  
    for (int i=0; i < tabs.length; i++)
            {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i])
                                     .setIcon(NewsFeedActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(ICONS[i]))
                                     .setTabListener(this));
            }//endfor
```

Comment: i have added the comment inside of my code and this is my first comment in stack overflow.

Comment: I think the code is pretty self explanatory and the code is well commented. Thank you for your submission.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check out the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library.

This is very good example for swipe-able tabs.