# Add image on 3 tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

How can I add images into tab ? Currently I'm able to move the tab to bottom but have no idea on how to change the  `LL Tab1`, `LL Tab2`, `LL Tab3` to icon.Am I on the right path ?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

[image]

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) from [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to meet [material design guidelines for tabs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html).

> The Design library’s `TabLayout` implements both fixed tabs, where the
>   view’s width is divided equally between all of the tabs, as well as
>   scrollable tabs, where the tabs are not a uniform size and can scroll
>   horizontally.

To implement `TabLayout` check this [guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout) and [how to add the icon for swipeable tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528687/how-to-add-the-icon-for-swipeable-tabs) to set icons to tabs using `setIcon`.

```
final int[] ICONS = new int[]{
        R.drawable.ic_action_document,
        R.drawable.ic_action_tick,
        R.drawable.ic_action_trash};
        ....
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(ICONS[0]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(ICONS[1]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(ICONS[2]);
```

To set the tabs at the bottom in a `TabLayout` check -  [How can I set tabs at the bottom and also hide top actionbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984706/how-can-i-set-tabs-at-the-bottom-and-also-hide-top-actionbar?lq=1) where you put the TabLayout in a relativeLayout and align it to parent bottom:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff00ff"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
```

Although you can put your tab layout at the bottom, try not to use bottom tab bars if possible as per the [Pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html) guide.

> Other platforms use the bottom tab bar to switch between the app's
>   views. Per platform convention, Android's tabs for view control are
>   shown in action bars at the top of the screen instead.

Answer (score 7):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }
 private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout for Tab**
*activity_main.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragments(Class) used in this tab

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

}
```

**Xml file**
fragment_one.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.OneFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**TwoFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;



    public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{

        public TwoFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        }

    }
```

**fragment_two.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.TwoFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can create third fragment class, and layout as i have done above.

Run it. Hope this would work

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

puth this activity_main.xml and set the custom height to TabLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
       app:tabMode="fixed"
       app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Create an xml layout named custom_tab.xml under res ⇒ layout. In this layout we have defined the custom view for the tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="@dimen/tab_label"
android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"/>
```

Open MainActivity.java and modify the code as below. Here if you observe setupTabIcons() method, I have rendered custom_tab.xml layout in each tab using below lines of code.

```
TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("ONE");
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabTwo.setText("TWO");
tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_call, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabThree.setText("THREE");
tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,Really interesting.Must be the solution

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score -1):

Well you can either place an ImageView in your Linearlayout that is each tab, or you can set an drawable as a background for your LinearLayout. If your image will act a background then you will obviously want to add that image as a background and not add an ImageView as a child to your LinearLayout. If it is going to be content though, not a background, you should add an ImageView to each LinearLayout like you would add a child of any other type to a parent View.

Comment: I set an drawable as a background for LinearLayout but image not showing